# error in conversion of raster file to postscript file

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I am trying to convert PWG raster file data into postscript data. I have generated at test file which is as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 5100 6600
%Creator: Cups-Filters
%LanguageLevel: 2
%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%EndComments
%BeginProlog
%EndProlog

%Pages: (atend)
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
<< /PageSize[5100 6600]/ImagingBBox null>> setpagedevice
%%EndPageSetup
gsave
gsave
5100 6600 scale
5100 6600 8 [5100 0 0 -6600 0 6600]
{currentfile 3 5100 string readhexstring pop} bind
false 3 colorimage

...hexadecimal information cut...

grestore
showpage
%PageTrailer
%Trailer
%%Pages: 1
%EOF
```

Whenever I try to run the program using GhostScript interpretor, I get the following error:

```
$ ghostscript sample.ps 
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /typecheck in --colorimage--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   3   (\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000...)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1976   1   3   %oparray_pop   1960   1   3   %oparray_pop   1852   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1878   7   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1194/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 399
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

The PS file is about 128 MB with about 99% data being the hexadecimal representation of the coloured image.

I tried searching it and one source suggested to add 'setpagedevice' parameter to the PS file. I have added it but to no effect.

How can I get rid of this error ? Also, is there any other way to represent very large images in postscript ?

Comment: have you tried it without the bind after the `{currentfile 3 5100 string readhexstring pop}`? I don't see it with bind in [PSLRM](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)

Comment: bind should not cause a problem, all that happens is that the operator definitions are replaced with their current values at the time of binding. So if you redefined, for example, readhexstring after the procedure, but before executing the procedure, you would get different results with and without binding. I'd suggest the problem is the code reading the data. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains:

```
{currentfile 3 5100 string readhexstring pop} bind
```

If we break that up and add comments about the stack content we get:

```
{
  currentfile    % Stack contents: -file-
  3              % stack contents: -file- 3
  5100           % stack contents: -file- 3 5100
  string         % string consumes the top operand, creates a string
                 % object of that size, and places the string on the stack
                 % stack contains: -file- 3 (string)
  readhexstring  % consume string and file operands, return substring, bool
                 %
  pop            % pop the boolean
}
```

The problem is that readhexstring expects to see -file- (string) but the stack **actually** contains 3 (string), 3 isn't a file object so you get a typecheck error.

Comment: That helped a lot (even for other things I was struggling with). I removed the '3' and everything works fine now. Thanks